# string.include? not working how I expect and I don't understand why

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a script to create an AWS stack using a Cloudformation template and Ruby to orchestrate it.  I want to check the stack doesn't already exist before building it, so have the following snippet of code

```
puts("Checking that stack " + stackName + " doesn't already exist")
puts

stackExists = `aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name #{stackName}`

puts(stackExists)


unless stackExists.include?("does not exist")
  puts("Stack " + stackName + " already exists.  Exiting.")
  exit(100)
end
```

Given that the output  of describe-stacks is a string that contains "does not exist" if the stack doesn't exist, I would expect to drop into the unless block if the stack exists and to skip over it if it doesn't, however, the output of my script is below when the stack does not already exist.

```
Checking that stack myStack doesn't already exist


A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the  DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id myStack does not exist

Stack myStack already exists.  Exiting.
```

If I do basically the same thing in irb, I got the output I expect as below.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id myStack does not exist"
=> "A client error (ValidationError) occurred when calling the DescribeStacks operation: Stack with id myStack does not exist"
irb(main):002:0> a.include?("does not exist")
=> true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I see, it should be working in ruby. I guess there might be something different happening with the `aws` command that is executed. why don't you try that command execution in irb instead of just trying with the string? do `stackExists = \`aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name #{stackName}\`` and `stackExists.include?("does not exist")` in your irb and see if it still works as expected. 
Also, also try calling `.strip` on the string object so that newline characters are removed. `stackExists.strip.include?("does not exist")`

Answer (score 1):

Ah thank you so much, I can see what's happening now. The string I am looking for is going to standard error not standard out, so stackExists actually equals nil.... I know how to fix this now, thanks!

I changed the code as follows to divert standard error to standard output as back ticks apparently do not allow you to directly capture standard error and this now works as expected...

```
stackExists = `aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name #{stackName} 2>&1`.strip


unless stackExists.include?("does not exist")
  puts("Stack " + stackName + " already exists.  Exiting.")
  exit(100)
end
```

Comment: Instead of saying "I know how to fix this now", it would useful for other newbies if you post how to fix it in the answer

Comment: Good point!  I will update my answer.  Thanks for the constructive feedback.